# Coletando os dados de uma array

Tags: java, array, algoritmo

Estou com um exercicio para a faculdade mas estou perdido na minha lógica e em como solucionar.
Eu tenho que coletar o resultados de jogos e definir a pontuação para cada resultado.
o vencedor leva 3 pontos, um empate garante 1 ponto e a derrota não da nenhum ponto.

Sei que não tenho muito ainda mas escrevi isso aqui:

**Obs: O professor pede que use apenas arrays bidimensionais string!**

(Define a two-dimensional array of Strings representing the results of matches. and a four-element array of ints representing scores of teams of Germany, Ireland,Poland and Scotland (in this order). The program calculates total score for each team (3 points for a win, 1 for a draw, 0 for a defeat), puts them into the array and then prints it)

**Obs2: esta inglês apenas porque estudo e moro na Polônia e o curso e em inglês.**

```
public class Jogos {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String [][] resultados = new String[12][4];

    resultados [0][0]="Alemanha";
    resultados [0][1]=2;
    resultados [0][2]="Escocia";
    resultados [0][3]=1;

    resultados [1][0]="Polonia";
    resultados [1][1]=2;
    resultados [1][2]="Alemanha";
    resultados [1][3]=0;

    resultados [2][0]="Alemanha";
    resultados [2][1]=1;
    resultados [2][2]="Irlanda";
    resultados [2][3]=1;

    resultados [3][0]="Polonia";
    resultados [3][1]=2;
    resultados [3][2]="Escocia";
    resultados [3][3]=2;

    resultados [4][0]="Escocia";
    resultados [4][1]=1;
    resultados [4][2]="Irlanda";
    resultados [4][3]=0;

    resultados [5][0]="Irlanda";
    resultados [5][1]=1;
    resultados [5][2]="Polonia";
    resultados [5][3]=1;

    resultados [6][0]="Irlanda";
    resultados [6][1]=1;
    resultados [6][2]="Escocia";
    resultados [6][3]=1;

    resultados [7][0]="Alemanha";
    resultados [7][1]=3;
    resultados [7][2]="Polonia";
    resultados [7][3]=1;

    resultados [8][0]="Escocia";
    resultados [8][1]=2;
    resultados [8][2]="Alemanha";
    resultados [8][3]=3;

    resultados [9][0]="Irlanda";
    resultados [9][1]=1;
    resultados [9][2]="Alemanha";
    resultados [9][3]=0;

    resultados [10][0]="Escocia";
    resultados [10][1]=2;
    resultados [10][2]="Polonia";
    resultados [10][3]=2;

    resultados [11][0]="Polonia";
    resultados [11][1]=2;
    resultados [11][2]="Irlanda";
    resultados [11][3]=1;

    for (int i=0; i<resultados.length; i++){
      for (int j=0; j<resultados[i].length; j++){
        System.out.print(resultados[i][j] + " - ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Essa modelação é forçada pelo exercício ? É que ela não é boa de todo.

Comment: ele pede para definir uma matriz bidimensional de String que represente os resultados das combinações em um torneio, listando os a pontuacao de cada time em uma lista.

Comment: Se é uma matriz bidimensional de `String` não é o que você tem no código neste momento. Tem como colocar o enunciado na pergunta também ? Ou pelo menos a parte que interessa dele?

Comment: Define a two-dimensional array of Strings representing the results of matches.
and a four-element array of ints representing scores of teams of Germany, Ireland,Poland and Scotland (in this order). The program calculates total score for each
team (3 points for a win, 1 for a draw, 0 for a defeat), puts them into the array and
then prints it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se apenas pode utilizar arrays bidimensionais de `Strings` a sua solução está no caminho correto, mas falta os cálculos dos pontos. Se é tudo uma `String` então será necessário interpretar o valor numérico dos golos com `Integer.parseInt` para se saber o resultado de cada jogo.

Faltou também ainda um array para as pontuações como o enunciado indica, que refere as equipas: Alemanha, Irlanda, Polônia e Escócia nesta ordem exata.

Uma solução possível seria:

```
public static int obterPosicao(String equipe){
    switch (equipe){
    case "Alemanha": return 0;
    case "Irlanda": return 1;
    case "Polonia": return 2;
    case "Escocia": return 3;
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] resultados = {
            {"Alemanha","2","Escocia","1"},
            {"Polonia","2","Alemanha","0"},
            {"Alemanha","1","Irlanda","1"},
            {"Polonia","2","Escocia","2"},
            {"Escocia","1","Irlanda","0"},
            {"Irlanda","1","Polonia","1"},
            {"Irlanda","1","Escocia","1"},
            {"Alemanha","3","Polonia","1"},
            {"Escocia","2","Alemanha","3"},
            {"Irlanda","1","Alemanha","0"},
            {"Escocia","2","Polonia","2"},
            {"Polonia","2","Irlanda","1"}       
    };

    int[] pontuacoes = new int[4];
    String[] nomes = {"Alemanha","Irlanda","Polonia","Escocia"};

    for (int i = 0; i < resultados.length; ++i){
        int golos1 = Integer.parseInt(resultados[i][1]);//posicao 1 é golos de equipe1
        int golos2 = Integer.parseInt(resultados[i][3]);//posicao 3 é golos de equipe2

        int score1 = 1, score2 = 1; //assume empate por defeito     
        if (golos1 > golos2){ //ajusta caso não seja
            score1 = 3;
            score2 = 0;
        }
        else if (golos1 < golos2){
            score1 = 0;
            score2 = 3;
        }

        //obtem a posição da equipa no vetor pontuacoes com base no nome e ajusta score
        pontuacoes[obterPosicao(resultados[i][0])] += score1; 
        pontuacoes[obterPosicao(resultados[i][2])] += score2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pontuacoes.length; ++i){
        System.out.println("Pontuação para " + nomes[i] + " é " + pontuacoes[i]);
    }
}
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/u30WLE)

Optei por simplificar algumas coisas, mais notoriamente a criação dos resultados. Também criei um array de nomes das equipas nas pontuações para ser simples de escrever os resultados finais na tela.

Certamente que daria para elaborar bastante na solução utilizando *HashMaps* por exemplo, mas suspeito que era uma solução desta natureza que o seu professor estivesse à espera.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Isac, eu mudei algumas coisas para adequar a minha realidade aqui e coloquei tudo em inglês! esta funcionando perfeitamente!

Answer (score 0):

Sugestão:

Defina os objetos e suas propriedades primeiro.

O time:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Team {

private String name;

public Team(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 17 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Team other = (Team) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

O jogo:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Game {

    private Team home;
    private Team visitor;

    private Integer homeScore;
    private Integer visitorScore;

    public static Game getGameInstance(Team home, Integer homeScore, Team visitor, Integer visitorScore) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.setHome(home);
        game.setVisitor(visitor);
        game.setHomeScore(homeScore);
        game.setVisitorScore(visitorScore);
        return game;
    }

    public Team getHome() {
        return home;
    }

    public Integer getHomePoints(){
        return 
                homeScore.equals(visitorScore) ? Result.DRAW :
                (homeScore > visitorScore ? Result.WIN : Result.LOSS)  ;
    }

    public Integer getVisitorPoints(){
        return 
                homeScore.equals(visitorScore) ? Result.DRAW :
                (homeScore < visitorScore ? Result.WIN : Result.LOSS)  ;
    }


    public void setHome(Team home) {
        this.home = home;
    }

    public Team getVisitor() {
        return visitor;
    }

    public void setVisitor(Team visitor) {
        this.visitor = visitor;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.home);
        hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.visitor);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Game other = (Game) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.home, other.home)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.visitor, other.visitor)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Integer getHomeScore() {
        return homeScore;
    }

    public void setHomeScore(Integer homeScore) {
        this.homeScore = homeScore;
    }

    public Integer getVisitorScore() {
        return visitorScore;
    }

    public void setVisitorScore(Integer visitorScore) {
        this.visitorScore = visitorScore;
    }



}
```

As pontuações:

```
package stackoverflow;

public class Result {
    public static final Integer DRAW = 1;
    public static final Integer WIN = 3;
    public static final Integer LOSS = 0;

}
```

Daí entao, coloque os resultados e calcule:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;


public class CalculaResultado {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Game> gameSet = new HashSet<>();

        final Team alemanha = new Team("Alemanha");
        final Team escocia = new Team("Escócia");
        final Team polonia = new Team("Polônia");
        final Team irlanda = new Team("Irlanda");

        Game game1 = Game.getGameInstance(alemanha, 2, escocia, 1);
        Game game2 = Game.getGameInstance(polonia, 2, alemanha, 0);
        Game game3 = Game.getGameInstance(alemanha, 1, irlanda, 1);
        Game game4 = Game.getGameInstance(polonia, 2, escocia, 2);
        Game game5 = Game.getGameInstance(escocia, 1, irlanda, 0);
        Game game6 = Game.getGameInstance(irlanda, 1, polonia, 1);
        Game game7 = Game.getGameInstance(irlanda, 1, escocia, 1);
        Game game8 = Game.getGameInstance(alemanha, 3, polonia, 1 );
        Game game9 = Game.getGameInstance(escocia, 2, alemanha, 3);
        Game game10 = Game.getGameInstance(irlanda, 1, alemanha, 0);
        Game game11 = Game.getGameInstance(escocia, 2, polonia, 2);
        Game game12 = Game.getGameInstance(polonia, 2, irlanda, 1);


        gameSet.add(game1);
        gameSet.add(game2);
        gameSet.add(game3);
        gameSet.add(game4);
        gameSet.add(game5);
        gameSet.add(game6);
        gameSet.add(game7);
        gameSet.add(game8);
        gameSet.add(game9);
        gameSet.add(game10);
        gameSet.add(game11);
        gameSet.add(game12);

        Map<Team, Integer> points = new HashMap<>();

        for (Game game : gameSet) {

            if ( !points.containsKey( game.getHome() ) ){
                points.put(game.getHome(), 0);
            }

            if ( !points.containsKey(game.getVisitor())){
                points.put(game.getVisitor(), 0);
            }

            points.put(game.getHome(), points.get(game.getHome()) + game.getHomePoints()  );
            points.put(game.getVisitor(), points.get(game.getVisitor()) + game.getVisitorPoints()  );

        }

        for (Map.Entry<Team, Integer> teamResult : points.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println( String.format("Pontuação %s : %d", teamResult.getKey().getName(), teamResult.getValue() ) );
        }
    }



}
```

**RESULTADO:**

Pontuação Polônia : 9 
Pontuação Irlanda : 6  
Pontuação Escócia : 6  
Pontuação Alemanha : 10

Comment: Boa resposta, mas não é muito legal pedir na resposta para que ela seja aceita. O recomendado é deixar que o autor decida ;)

Comment: Ola Carlos, muito obrigado pela ajuda! mas esta forma de solucao nao e o que o professor quer, sendo assim nao posso usar! ja havia visto sobre hashmap, mas nao posso usar neste caso! pois o professor pede exatamente isso..... 
Define a two-dimensional array of Strings representing the results of matches. and a four-element array of ints representing scores of teams of Germany, Ireland,Poland and Scotland (in this order). The program calculates total score for each team (3 points for a win, 1 for a draw, 0 for a defeat), puts them into the array and then prints it

Comment: @Articuno , tem razão. Editei.

Comment: @igorcamargo , eu poderia ter feito assim, se tivesse detalhado melhor a pergunta. Não havia restrições. Logo, se deseja chegar à resposta, considere editar sua pergunta.

Comment: @CarlosCariello Desculpa o erro foi todo meu! sou relativamente novo no forum e estou muito estressado por ter voltado a esdudar com 36 anos (matematica esta me matando)! me desculpa por ter lhe feito escrever uma solucao que nao pode ser usada!